# How to increase timing performace of a SQL query

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I'm using postgresql 9.6 on the 16GB Ubuntu-PC with 4 cores & SSD with following params:

```
max_connections = 200                   
shared_buffers = 6GB
work_mem = 256MB                              
maintenance_work_mem =1GB
```

How to increase performance of the SQL-query:

```
WITH ss AS (SELECT  
      time_noise, track, slow, distance, last_time
    FROM
        eco.noise
    WHERE
        (track, time_noise, slow) IN (
        SELECT
          DISTINCT ON (track)
          track, time_noise, slow 
        FROM
          eco.noise
        WHERE
          base_name='B001' AND slow >= 50 AND slow <= 90 AND distance <= 10000 AND time_noise >= '06-01-2019' AND time_noise <= '07-01-2019'
          ORDER BY track, slow DESC
        ) 
    ORDER BY time_noise)
SELECT
    COALESCE(to_char(ss.time_noise, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '') AS time_noise, ss.slow, ss.track, COALESCE(to_char(ss.last_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '') as last_time, ss.distance,
    eco.tracks.callsign, eco.tracks.altitude,eco.tracks.speed,eco.tracks.angle,eco.tracks.latitude,eco.tracks.longitude,eco.tracks.vertical_speed,
    eco.routes.from, eco.routes.to
FROM ss
LEFT JOIN eco.tracks ON ss.track  = eco.tracks.track AND eco.tracks.time_track = ss.last_time
LEFT JOIN eco.routes ON eco.tracks.callsign  = eco.routes.callsign
ORDER BY ss.time_noise ASC;
```

I use the following indexes:

```
 postgres  | eco         | eco.noise            | test_unique_noise_3         | f         | f          | btree      | 3 8 26 2 | {base_name,slow,distance,time_noise} | f             | f
 postgres  | eco         | eco.tracks           | tracks_time_track_track_key | t         | f          | btree      | 2 3      | {time_track,track}                   | f             | f
 postgres  | eco         | eco.routes           | pr_routes                   | t         | t          | btree      | 1        | {callsign}                           | f             | f
 postgres  | eco         | eco.noise            | test_unique_noise           | f         | f          | btree      | 25 2 8   | {track,time_noise,slow}              | f             | f
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Sort  (cost=3739384.97..3742913.97 rows=1411600 width=131) (actual time=2377.640..2377.805 rows=3792 loops=1)
       Sort Key: ss.time_noise
       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1087kB
       CTE ss
         ->  Sort  (cost=525472.51..529001.51 rows=1411600 width=32) (actual time=2161.522..2162.140 rows=3792 loops=1)
               Sort Key: noise.time_noise
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 393kB
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=369723.59..381285.34 rows=1411600 width=32) (actual time=2026.531..2160.723 rows=3792 loops=1)
                     ->  Unique  (cost=369723.02..370160.00 rows=3978 width=20) (actual time=2026.498..2142.201 rows=3791 loops=1)
                           ->  Sort  (cost=369723.02..369941.51 rows=87396 width=20) (actual time=2026.497..2117.520 rows=568059 loops=1)
                                 Sort Key: noise_1.track, noise_1.slow DESC
                                 Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 68956kB
                                 ->  Index Scan using test_unique_noise_3 on noise noise_1  (cost=0.56..362549.87 rows=87396 width=20) (actual time=0.039..1751.161 rows=568059 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((base_name = 'B001'::text) AND (slow >= '50'::double precision) AND (slow <= '90'::double precision) AND (distance <= 10000) AND (time_noise >= '2019-06-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (time_noise <= '2019-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                     ->  Index Scan using test_unique_noise on noise  (cost=0.56..2.78 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=3791)
                           Index Cond: ((track = noise_1.track) AND (time_noise = noise_1.time_noise) AND (slow = noise_1.slow))
       ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=17792.76..3066196.28 rows=1411600 width=131) (actual time=2351.691..2376.080 rows=3792 loops=1)
             Hash Cond: (tracks.callsign = routes.callsign)
             ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.56..3021978.00 rows=1411600 width=67) (actual time=2161.540..2179.800 rows=3792 loops=1)
                   ->  CTE Scan on ss  (cost=0.00..28232.00 rows=1411600 width=32) (actual time=2161.524..2162.558 rows=3792 loops=1)
                   ->  Index Scan using tracks_time_track_track_key on tracks  (cost=0.56..2.11 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=3792)
                         Index Cond: ((time_track = ss.last_time) AND (ss.track = track))
             ->  Hash  (cost=10017.64..10017.64 rows=621964 width=15) (actual time=189.279..189.279 rows=610992 loops=1)
                   Buckets: 1048576  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 37585kB
                   ->  Seq Scan on routes  (cost=0.00..10017.64 rows=621964 width=15) (actual time=0.017..65.022 rows=610992 loops=1)
     Planning time: 0.646 ms
     Execution time: 2380.094 ms
```

As I understand the bottleneck is CTE because of 'WITH', so I've tried to use subquery.. but similar result;

```
   SELECT
      sub.time_noise AS time_noise, sub.slow, sub.track, sub.last_time as last_time, sub.temperature, sub.humadity, sub.presure, sub.wind, sub.distance,
      eco.tracks.callsign, eco.tracks.altitude,eco.tracks.speed,eco.tracks.angle,eco.tracks.latitude,eco.tracks.longitude,eco.tracks.vertical_speed,
      eco.routes.from, eco.routes.to
  FROM (SELECT  
    time_noise, track, slow, distance, last_time
  FROM
      eco.noise
  WHERE
      (track, time_noise, slow) IN (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT ON (track)
        track, time_noise, slow 
      FROM
        eco.noise
      WHERE
        base_name='B001' AND slow >= 50 AND slow <= 100 AND distance <= 10000 AND time_noise >= '01-01-2019' AND time_noise <= '07-01-2019' 
        ORDER BY track, slow DESC
      ) 
  ORDER BY time_noise) as sub
  LEFT JOIN eco.tracks ON sub.track  = eco.tracks.track AND eco.tracks.time_track = sub.last_time
  LEFT JOIN eco.routes ON eco.tracks.callsign  = eco.routes.callsign
  ORDER BY sub.time_noise ASC;
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1066367.20..4077589.03 rows=1411652 width=83) (actual time=3943.936..3992.130 rows=9262 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1066366.64..1069895.77 rows=1411652 width=48) (actual time=3943.917..3945.328 rows=9262 loops=1)
         Sort Key: noise.time_noise
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1108kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=907649.38..922173.77 rows=1411652 width=48) (actual time=3582.100..3941.579 rows=9262 loops=1)
               ->  Unique  (cost=907648.81..911048.44 rows=3978 width=20) (actual time=3582.059..3891.212 rows=9253 loops=1)
                     ->  Sort  (cost=907648.81..909348.63 rows=679925 width=20) (actual time=3582.058..3826.172 rows=1450072 loops=1)
                           Sort Key: noise_1.track, noise_1.slow DESC
                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 162439kB
                           ->  Index Scan using test_unique_noise_3 on noise noise_1  (cost=0.56..841781.02 rows=679925 width=20) (actual time=0.043..2864.183 rows=1450072 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: ((base_name = 'B001'::text) AND (slow >= '50'::double precision) AND (slow <= '100'::double precision) AND (distance <= 10000) AND (time_noise >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (time_noise <= '2019-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               ->  Index Scan using test_unique_noise on noise  (cost=0.56..2.78 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=9253)
                     Index Cond: ((track = noise_1.track) AND (time_noise = noise_1.time_noise) AND (slow = noise_1.slow))
   ->  Index Scan using tracks_time_track_track_key on tracks  (cost=0.56..2.11 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=9262)
         Index Cond: ((time_track = noise.last_time) AND (noise.track = track))
 Planning time: 0.782 ms
 Execution time: 3994.348 ms
```

Should I use PL/pgpsql e.g?

Comment: You don't actually need the `distinct on()` in the sub-query (because the outcome of the `IN` operator will not be affected by duplicates). If you get rid of that, you can also get rid of the `order by` in there. Maybe that improves the performance

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Are you sure? The `DISTINCT ON` might eliminate some triples.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: no, I am not sure - my guess is that removing duplicates from that sub-query is more expensive than ignoring them while evaluating the IN clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My point is that if there are two triples `('a', NULL, 100)` and `('a', NULL, 50)`, then the `DISTINCT ON` will eliminate the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index scan can only use the first two columns (`base_name` and `slow`) for the scan itself, the remaining ones are used as a filter (before table access).
But your query is probably slow because it has to access the table 1.5 million times to fetch the `track` column.

You should create an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON noise (base_name, track, slow DESC, distance, time_noise);
```

Then make sure that `noise` is vacuumed regularly, and you should get an *index only scan*, which is much faster, and you won't need an explicit sort as well.

Comment: Thank you! it works 1.5 times faster, but what do you mean by vacuumed..?

Comment: Try to `VACUUM (ANALYZE) noise` and see if that improves anything. Are you seeing an index only scan? You could add the new execution plan to your question.